# Plausibility of implants that hijack our emotions to improve human mental performance

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, artificial-intelligence, brain

Set in the near future (2030 A.D.): the Chinese government initiates a nationwide program aiming to create a new generation of people who are more objective and less prone to making stupid decisions by attaching electronic implants into the limbic cortex of the brain to regulate the levels of serotonin, dopamine, adrenaline and oxytocin.

The 4 crucial chemicals are released and controlled by our endocrine system and serve as a very powerful tool to control our state of emotions but as we progress technologically and socially, our own limbic system starts to experience huge mood swings likely induced by external stress stimuli.

I'm wondering about the plausibility of implementing these implants to help people make decisions more efficiently? I'm talking about efficiency not making good judgement but can I safely assume zero procrastination and fewer worries can be translated into high productivity and performance?

I believe procrastination is due to lack of motivation so the implants would adjust neurotransmitter levels to trick our brain reward center to work harder for prolonged duration.

Comment: The *RoboCop* movie from 2014 goes briefly into this territory in the first half. Then the latter halfof the movie doesn't bring it up again but I still found it an interesting philosophical question incorporated. Basically, they found that the titular RoboCop was too human and emotional which impeded his performance with all the emotion stuff against purely artificial intelligence agents that tactically assess situation and act immediately.

Comment: I am sorry, but the Chinese do not need to make FUTURE modifications to do this. Frankly, the Chinese culture has already achieved this state. It's called 'education'.

Comment: that is not just improving metal health that is down right mind control, you could create fanatical zealot soldiers, sociopath's or work addicts who starve to death working just by triggering the right chemical release for the right stimuli. If the control system is smart enough to tell when someone is procrastinating it can control their entire behavioral patterns.

Comment: @John it's definitely a dystopian level of scary potential here. You essentially have meat automatons at your disposal to program as you please.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### We already have "anti procrastination" drugs. They usually work, but sometimes fail dismally.

Modavigil (aka modafinil, adavigial, artmodagival, etc) is a mild stimulant that can be purchased from the grey side of the net. In Australia; It is not illegal to posses or import, and while it can be prescribed under government subsidy in certain conditions, if you want it for performance enhancing uses you need to buy it from shady websites that only take bitcoin.

Having consumed modavigil before, I can attest to its performance enhancing properties, and its procrastination-busting power, however, it doesnt always help me focus on the problem I wanted to.

Sometimes I'll fly through my assigned work and hit record productivity. Its helped with renovations. Its helped me focus on long boring tasks like renovating my website or even gardening.

However one night I had a deadline at work so took modavigil to help me stay focused into the evening. 2 hours later the power tripped, rather than just flip it back on, I decided to investigate what was going wrong. (I had decent electrical tools and half an electrical engineering degree). 4 hours later the sun is coming up and I'm halfway through rewiring my fuse box, deadline long forgotten about.

I've also remembered an unfinished side quest in a game and just stopped working to focus on that. 9 hours later I've gotten the quest completed and realise I've neglected work. ***The drug stopped me procrastinating about my important gaming***, and it stopped me wasting time doing the actual work that gives me money.

And then it doesn't help you with sleep - if you focus on a task and work through the night (as I often do) you'll be sleepy and unproductive tomorrow.

#### Procrastination != Lazy in fields where you need Eureka moments.

I'll make the argument that with some professions you can't improve productivity by removing that idle time spent not visibly working.

Many times it is, especially with menial work. Yes I need to clean my kitchen. No I didn't do it. Yes it was because I was procrastinating. Yes if I didn't procrastinate I would've been more productive. Same would apply to shelf stacking, construction, etc.

But sometimes it isn't. Working as an engineer, I'm often fleshing out a solution idly in the back of my head when not visibly working. The number of times I've solved a complex problem while in the shower is high enough I should be claiming my water bill as a tax deduction. Counter to this, the number of times I've realised a future problem before it stops us, while not visibly working, is also quite high.

Once I had a deadline due the next day. I sat at my desk at the office till 2am working the problem professionally and got no-where. I went home, went to bed, and started thinking about something else as I was nearing sleep. The eureka moment came after an hour of letting my mind wander. I was able to write the code in an hour and meet my deadline. Had I not "slacked off" I wouldn't have had that Eureka moment, and my company wouldn't have made the sale.

Were I to have this anti-procrastination implant, I would spend more time at my desk with the IDE open, making anyone walking past think I'm very productive, but without that time to let my mind wander I wouldn't have those Eureka moments, and would have much lower productivity.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is being tested, to the point of being the subject of an article on [Nature](https://www.nature.com/news/ai-controlled-brain-implants-for-mood-disorders-tested-in-people-1.23031)

> Researchers funded by the US military are developing appliances to record neural activity and automatically stimulate the brain to treat mental illness.
>
> Brain implants that deliver electrical pulses tuned to a person’s feelings and behaviour are being tested in people for the first time. Two teams funded by the US military’s research arm, the Defense Advanced Research Projects Agency (DARPA), have begun preliminary trials of ‘closed-loop’ brain implants that use algorithms to detect patterns associated with mood disorders. These devices can shock the brain back to a healthy state without input from a physician.
>
> The work, presented last week at the Society for Neuroscience (SfN) meeting in Washington DC, could eventually provide a way to treat severe mental illnesses that resist current therapies. It also raises thorny ethical concerns, not least because the technique could give researchers a degree of access to a person’s inner feelings in real time.
>
> The general approach — using a brain implant to deliver electric pulses that alter neural activity — is known as deep-brain stimulation. It is used to treat movement disorders such as Parkinson’s disease, but has been less successful when tested against mood disorders. Early evidence suggested that constant stimulation of certain brain regions could ease chronic depression, but a major study involving 90 people with depression found no improvement after a year of treatment. [...]
>
> At the SfN meeting, electrical engineer Omid Sani of the University of Southern California in Los Angeles — who is working with Chang’s team — showed the first map of how mood is encoded in the brain over time. He and his colleagues worked with six people with epilepsy who had implanted electrodes, tracking their brain activity and moods in detail over the course of one to three weeks. By comparing the two types of information, the researchers could create an algorithm to ‘decode’ that person’s changing moods from their brain activity. Some broad patterns emerged, particularly in brain areas that have previously been associated with mood.

This about controlling the mood. If this will then help to be more efficient in decision making is another story.
Procrastination is due to a lack of or insufficient prioritization with respect to other tasks: if my kitchen is burning I will gladly procrastinate my decision on what to put in my sandwich in favor of running out of the place. A device that stops this is going to make me take very poor decisions.

Comment: Thank you. I was going to write these but I'm glad you have done the research. There's also research of electrical stimulation to *overstimulate* parts of the brain, causing it to reduce activity. As brain halves are suspected to inhibit some activity in each other, the other brain half can then be actibe more freely. They can get interesting results for their calculus or creativity. Still a small developing field and critics are afraid of damages, but might help in the long run.

Comment: The Americans have been using prescription medications to do this for decades. Unfortunately, there is no vaccine to prevent stupidity. It seems it is very, very contagious. It spreads like wildfire throughout a population.

Answer (score 2):

## We do not yet know

Surely something like this must be possible, given the existence of mind-altering drugs like [ecstasy](https://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/drugfacts/mdma-ecstasymolly), [opiates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphine), and [SSRI antidepressants](https://www.webmd.com/depression/ssris-myths-and-facts-about-antidepressants).  But the fact is, we can tell you what the effects (generally) of these things are (even if how well antidepressants work [is up for debate](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK361016/)) but we don't really have much more than a vague idea *how* these drugs work.  Even for the ones with an understood mechanism, we just don't really have a good understanding of how that translates into the observed effects.  At least, not a finer grained one than "you bang on the side of the TV, the picture gets better".

Honestly, your proposed method of action (modulating the effects of these 4 neurotransmitters) may or may not work.  We simply don't know enough about how the brain actually works to be able to say definitively say one way or another.

Put another way - my understanding is that not even an expert in the state of the art in neuroscience could give you an answer with any degree of real accuracy.  Oddly enough, this means the more details you try to put in, the less gracefully your story is likely to age.

## What this means for you

This is almost certainly possible (given the existence of mind-affecting drugs, electroshock therapy, and so on).  From a reality check perspective, yeah, there's no problem here.

I would simply be as vague as possible.  When talking about the tech, say it uses a mix of mind-machine interface and neurotransmitter chicanery.  Name drop mind-altering drugs and deep brain stimulation treatments that exist today, as being the very earliest foundational work in the field.  Other than that, the less you say about how (exactly) it works, the better.